# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'StandardScaler

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

Hello guys thank you for stopping by,
I have a problem when I am trying to get the prediction form training model, I have tried lots of codes to solve this, basically, my data contain so many types and this is a [sample of my data](http://www.mediafire.com/file/kd5k7c7x2083eha/R_training_set.csv/file) and I want to StandardScaler my data...
here the original code...

```
# Load the training set
df = pd.read_csv('training_data/R_training_set.csv', 
low_memory=False)
df = df.dropna(how='any',axis=0)
df.shape

ohe_fields=['one_way','surface_type','street_type','hour','weekday','month']

# One-Hot encode a couple of variables
df_ohe = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=ohe_fields)

# Get the one-hot variable names
ohe_feature_names = pd.get_dummies(df[ohe_fields],columns=ohe_fields).columns.tolist()
df_ohe.head()
```

this is what my data look like

[image]

```
 # Sinuosity is typically close to 1, even for moderately curvy roads. A high sinuosity means a longer road.
feature_transforms = {
    'sinuosity': np.log
}
for feature,transform in feature_transforms.items():
    df_ohe[feature] = transform(df_ohe[feature])

# Continuously valued features
float_feature_names = [
    'accident_counts',
    'speed_limit',
    'aadt',
    'surface_width',
    'sinuosity',
    'euclidean_length',
    'segment_length',
    'road_orient_approx',
    'Rain',
    'dust',
    'temperature',
    'visibility',
    'wind_speed',
    'proximity_to_billboard',
    'proximity_to_major_road',
    'proximity_to_signal',
    'proximity_to_nearest_intersection',
    'proximity_to_nearest_exit',
    'population_density',
    'Hopspot'
]
float_features = df_ohe.xs(float_feature_names,axis=1).values

# Use scikit-learn's StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
float_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(float_features)
#print (float_features.mean(axis=0))

df_ohe[float_feature_names] = float_scaled
with open('scalers_4.pkl','wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(scaler,fp)


y = df['target'].values
binary_feature_names = [
    'dew_point_temperature',
    'EXTREME_AIR_TEMPERATURE',
    'at_exit',
    'at_intersection',
]
df_ohe = df_ohe.xs(float_feature_names+binary_feature_names+ohe_feature_names,axis=1)


X = df_ohe.values
y = df['target'].values
feature_names = df_ohe.columns.tolist()


wrangler = {
    'float_scaler_mean': float_features.mean(axis=0),
    'float_scaler_std': float_scaled,
    'float_feature_names': float_feature_names,
    'ohe_fields': ohe_fields,
    'feature_names': feature_names,
    'feature_transforms': feature_transforms 
}
```

P.S I used xgboost Algorithm for training data

```
with open('wrangler_2.pkl','rb') as fp:
    wrangler = pickle.load(fp)
float_scaler_mean = wrangler['float_scaler_mean']
float_scaler_std = wrangler['float_scaler_std']
float_feature_names = wrangler['float_feature_names']
ohe_fields = wrangler['ohe_fields']
feature_names = wrangler['feature_names']
booster = xgboost.Booster()
booster.load_model('new_0003.model')


def make_test_set(df,wrangler):
    float_scaler_mean = wrangler['float_scaler_mean']
    float_scaler_std = wrangler['float_scaler_std']
    float_feature_names = wrangler['float_feature_names']
    ohe_fields = wrangler['ohe_fields']
    feature_names = wrangler['feature_names']
    print(len(feature_names))
    df_ohe = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=ohe_fields)

    float_features = df.xs(float_feature_names,axis=1).values
    float_features = (float_features - float_scaler_mean) / float_scaler_std
    for i,fname in enumerate(float_feature_names):
        df_ohe[fname] = float_features[:,i]

    empty_features = list(set(feature_names) - set(df_ohe.columns.tolist()))

    #for f in empty_features:
    #df_ohe[f] = 0

    df_ohe = df_ohe[feature_names]#.drop(columns=['SegID.1','geometry','SHAPE']+drop_columns,errors='ignore')

    print(df_ohe.columns)
    print(df_ohe.columns.tolist())
    X = df_ohe.values
    feature_names = df_ohe.columns.tolist()
    return X, feature_names

X,names = make_test_set(test_df,wrangler)
print (X.shape)
print (X[0])
```

i get the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'StandardScaler'
```

Did I do something wrong?
Guide me to the right way thank you...

Comment: Do you think your `wrangler = {
    'float_scaler_mean': scaler}` value actually be `wrangler = {
    'float_scaler_mean': float_features.mean(axis=0)}`

Answer (score 0):

When you have created your `wrangler` variable, you have passed the `scaler` value which is a `StandardScalar` object. Trying to assume what you want to do when you define the `wrangler`, I can think of:

```
wrangler = {
    'float_scaler_mean': float_features.mean(axis=0),
    'float_scaler_std': float_scaled,
    'float_feature_names': float_feature_names,
    'ohe_fields': ohe_fields,
    'feature_names': feature_names,
    'feature_transforms': feature_transforms 
}
```

What is it that you exactly wanna do? You cannot do `float_features = (float_features - float_scaler_mean) / float_scaler_std` with a `StandardScaler` object as `float_scaler_mean`

Comment: I want to do the first one @pissall

Comment: @MaramMubarak That solves it then. Hope it helped. Please upvote and select the answer if it did

Comment: okay I will try it and let you know thank you so much @pissall

Comment: still the problem in line `float_features = (float_features - float_scaler_mean) / float_scaler_std`  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'StandardScaler' ` @pissall

Comment: @MaramMubarak Can you update your code and error in the question?

Comment: @MaramMubarak Code looks fine, please print `wrangler` variable. Provide the shape of `float_features.mean(axis=0).shape`

Comment: You should definitely not get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'StandardScaler'`, remove `.shape` from your `.mean()` and then show

Comment: yes, I didn't get this error I got `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (143097,20) (382196,20)` also when i remove it the same error https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKCnQ.png @pissall

Comment: @MaramMubarak Look I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, and you're being very unclear about your errors and inputs. Now you have different shapes for your columns, where as you need both the number of rows to be the same

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear before I'm trying to use the same code here with my own data https://github.com/dwilson1988/traffic-collisions when you read this you will understand better... @pissall